# expired certificates and chrome

Tags: google-chrome, certificate

Yesterday I've visited a website for the first time, but now Chrome raises an error when I connect to this website. The error is:

`the connection is not private - ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID`

So I tried to inspect the certificate, and I read that it expires today (25-03-2015).

My clock is right.

So, is there a way to force chrome to update this certificate?

Comment: Are you sure a new certificate has been issued.  Chrome should handle this automatically.  If the date is correct then the likely culprit is your anti-virus.

Comment: No, I'm not sure, how can I know it?

Comment: Ok now I have a new certificate, it will expire in 3 years.